# How to reopen a 2D Blender File?

Tags: animation, 3d-view, 2d

I made a 2D animation in blender and saved it. But when I reopen the file, it opens up in the 3D form with the 2D part on a flat plane in the space. How do I change it so that the camera faces the 2D animation straight again?

Comment: upload your blend file is easier to help if you can analyze

Comment: I would say show a screenshots first to help others identify what you expect to see and what you get. Also if uploading file use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @BlenderBlackened  We ideally want questions to be answerable without having to download anything (so that in future people can easily tell if this question relates to their's), so asking for images first is preferable and looking at a blend file is a last resort.

Comment: @RayMairlot I'm sorry, I forget that here they are experts and todologists and that they have a thondera eye embedded in their forehead and can see beyond the obvious, and I'm not asking you to download anything

Comment: and each one is a different world and each world has its own way of solving things

Answer (score 1):

When doing 2d animation, you are still in 3d space but your camera is positioned vertically above the drawing plane.

So to get back you just

- press <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> if there is a camera in the scene
- or press <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> to go into
  top view with the viewport camera.

Comment: This is not exactly the case, even if you have a close idea, even if there is a camera in space if it has not been selected, it is very likely and almost 100% possible that you will not get the correct view of the camera, in addition there is the fact that for 2D you have to assign the spelling view of the camera

Answer (score 0):

- select your **CAMERA** and
- **press** <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>
- and go to **Camera** options and select **<kbd>ORTHOGRAPHIC VIEW</kbd>**

[image: example]
[image]